# Error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous For string template

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error for  part of my template, for  this is working fine. I would love to handle this error myself but I don't even know what this means. Maybe my operator overload syntax is incorrect? But even without my operator loading method I still get the same error

```
node.h(12): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(992): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(987): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(987): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, int)'
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\node.h(10) : while compiling class template member function 'Node<T>::Node(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\redblacktree.cpp(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Node<T>::Node(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\redblacktree.cpp(203) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Node<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\redblacktree.cpp(197) : while compiling class template member function 'bool RedBlackTree<T>::remove(T)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal.cpp(240) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool RedBlackTree<T>::remove(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\aaron\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal\redblacktreefinal.cpp(213) : see reference to class template instantiation 'RedBlackTree<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>          ]
```

My node.h file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

template <class T>
class Node {

    public :

        Node<T>(void) {
            parent  = NULL;
            left    = NULL;
            right   = NULL;
            data    = NULL;
            isBlack = false;
        }
        Node<T>(T x){
            parent  = NULL;
            left    = NULL;
            right   = NULL;
            data    = x;
            isBlack = false; 
        }
        Node<T>(const Node<T>* & nd){
            parent  = nd->parent;
            left    = nd->left;
            right   = nd->right;
            data    = nd->data;
            isBlack = nd->isBlack;
        }

        Node<T> & Node<T>::operator = (const Node<T>* & nd){
            parent  = nd->parent;
            left    = nd->left;
            right   = nd->right;
            data    = nd->data;
            isBlack = nd->isBlack;
            return* this;
        }

        Node<T>* parent;
        Node<T>* left;
        Node<T>* right;

        T   data;
        bool  isBlack;

    private :

};
```

How it's being used

```
void part2()
{
  cout << endl << endl << "REDBLACKTREE<STRING>";
  cout << endl << "insert file and print contents (load, dump)" << endl;
  RedBlackTree<string> rb;
  string fname = "part2.txt"; //should contain strings
  int n = 0;

  // read file and load contents into tree
  string* arr = readFile<string>(fname, n);
  rb.load(arr, n);

  // read contents from tree into array
  int out_n = 0;
  string* out = rb.dump(out_n);

  // print dumped contents
  int count = 0;
  for(int i=0; i < out_n; i++){
         if(count % 5 == 0){
                 cout << endl;
         }
         cout << left << setw(13) << out[i];
         count ++;
  }
  cout << endl;
  statsPrint(rb, 174, 5, 9, true);

  // remove all items from tree
  cout << endl << endl << "empty tree one item at a time";
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
         rb.remove(arr[i]);
  }
  statsPrint(rb, 0, 0, 0, true);

  delete[] arr;
  delete[] out;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
    Node<T>(void) {
        parent  = NULL;
        left    = NULL;
        right   = NULL;
        data    = NULL; // <----- Remove this line - this is causing the errors
        isBlack = false;
    }
```

Edit: Here's a small C++ program that isolates this error:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string data;
  data = NULL; // error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘data = 0’
  return 0;
}
```

Based on the error message, it seems that the `NULL`, which is a `0`, can either be interpreted as a `char` or `const *char`. Hence the `error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ message.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Original post:

This is a strange signature for a `operator=` overload:

```
Node<T> & Node<T>::operator = (const Node<T>* & nd)
```

Usually it's just

```
Node<T> & Node<T>::operator = (const Node<T> & nd)
```

without the asterisk. This may remove the ambiguity that the compiler is complaining about. Of course you will have to change the `->` to a `.` in that function.

Comment: Didn't do the trick. The error still occurs even without the overloading method.

Comment: Updated. Just delete the line `data    = NULL;` in the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can change operator= to this:

```
Node<T>& operator=(const Node<T>* & nd){
    parent  = nd->parent;
    left    = nd->left;
    right   = nd->right;
    data    = nd->data;
    isBlack = nd->isBlack;
    return* this;
}
```

beacause operator= is not outside class Node.

Comment: Still get the error, the ambiguity error occurs even without the overloading method.

Comment: It is too strange. I copy your code, test in QtCreator and VS2010, it runs very well.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the same change as above to the copy constructor as well.  The syntax of your functions implies that you want to assign a node* to a node object which does not make sense.

For example:

```
node1 = &node2; // Assign a pointer to an object.  I'm guessing that you don't want to do this.  This is not a sensible operation
node1 = node2; // assign one object to another.  This is what you want to do right?
```

By the way, you really need to show us an example of how the class is used.  Write a simple main function that shows how you are actually trying to do the assignment, and then add that to your post so that others and see and compile exactly what you are doing.

Moreover, I'm not clear about why you are overloading the operator= and copy constructor.  Since you are not deep copying the pointers there is no reason to do it in the first place.  It is not a good idea to write those functions unnecessarily.  In the below code, you can see that nodes can be copied just fine.  That is because your assignment operator will not be called.  You must be doing something strange in your source.  If you would like more help, then please modify this example to show us how the compiler error can be caused.  We need to see specifically how you copy node objects/pointers.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Node<int> node1;
    Node<int> node2;
    Node<int> node3;
    Node<int> node4;

    node1.left = &node2;
    node1.right = &node3;
    node1.parent = &node4;
    node1.isBlack = true;

    Node<int> node5;
    node5 = node1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Done. The reason I didn't want to post is that my node class is being used by my RedBlackTree class and I didn't want to post the entire redblacktree class

Comment: That example does not help because nobody here can compile that.  I meant, make an example that duplicates the compiler error by showing us a short example of how you copy nodes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I stated this more than once. The ambiguity error occurs even without copying any nodes

Comment: Perhaps you should re--read your post because I don't see where you stated it even one single time.  Being rude to people that are trying to help you will get you nowhere.  I was able to generate an error by assigning a node object to a node pointer very easily, which is what you are doing in your constructor.  I'm unclear about why you need to try to assign a pointer to an object.  Someone else also pointed out the data = NULL issue in the constructor.